# Not getting multiple substitutions in Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to perform multiple substitutions on a single line of text, and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
QUEUE(DLR_BRKR_TIXX_IN_PROD) TYPE(QLOCAL) CURDEPTH(0) QUEUE(DLR_BRKR_TIXX_OUT_PROD) TYPE(QLOCAL) CURDEPTH(0) QUEUE(TKT_BRKR_TIXX_IN_2) TYPE(QLOCAL) CURDEPTH(0) QUEUE(TKT_BRKR_TIXX_OUT_2) TYPE(QLOCAL) CURDEPTH(0)

Regex: s/QUEUE\(([^)]*)\).*CURDEPTH\((\d+)\)/\1:\2/g
```

This is only matching and substituting on the first match: QUEUE(DLR_BRKR_TIXX_IN_PROD) TYPE(QLOCAL) CURDEPTH(0).

Am I missing something very obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: you should always enable warning when developing Perl code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll find that it in fact matches from the first to the last match in one go because the `.*` is greedy.

Try

```
s/QUEUE\(([^)]*)\).*?CURDEPTH\((\d+)\)/\1:\2/g
```

instead.

Comment: You beat me for seconds :-( , +1.

Comment: sunofa.  I tried the non-greedy matching, but in a different location.  Thanks!